# Search Bar Widget problem about Preferred Size Widget

Tags: flutter, dart, searchbar

I'm creating a mobile app by using flutter framework. I want to add a search bar to my home page. Home page and Search bar files are separate than each other. Here is my home_screen.dart file

```
import 'package:amazon/widget/search_bar_widget.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: SearchBarWidget(),
      body: Center(
        child: Text("Home Screen"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And here is my search_bar_widget.dart file:

```
import 'package:amazon/utils/constants.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SearchBarWidget extends StatelessWidget with PreferredSizeWidget {
  SearchBarWidget({Key? key}) : preferredSize = Size.fromHeight(kAppBarHeight), super(key: key);

  @override
  final Size preferredSize;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.pink,
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the error message:`The class 'PreferredSizeWidget' can't be used as a mixin because it's neither a mixin class nor a mixin.`

I tried to change the `class SearchBarWidget extends StatelessWidget with PreferredSizeWidget` code into `class SearchBarWidget extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget`  and it doesn't give any error but still I can't see any pink container. I also tried this code for the search_bar_widget.dart

```
class SearchBarWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const SearchBarWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(80.0),
        child: Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: <Color>[Colors.blue, Colors.pink],
            ),
          ),
          //child: const AppBarContent(),
        ),
      ),
      body: const Center(
        child: Text('Content'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But this time home_screen.dart gives this error: `The argument type 'SearchBarWidget' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'PreferredSizeWidget?'.`

I would be grateful if you help.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you could try this

Add a Size to preferredSize, for example like this, that worked for me:

```
@override
Size get preferredSize => const Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight);
```

And also implement PreferredSizeWidget to your class

```
class SearchBarWidget extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget
```

Use `kToolbarHeight` as @Ampersanda proposed on comments

**EDIT**

What I have mentioned on the comment. If you look at your code, inside your `AppBar` on your `HomeScreen` you are creating a new `Scaffold.

For what I have understood, you want something like this:

[image: AppBar]

This is the code I have used to create this.

```
class SearchBarWidget extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  const SearchBarWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
      flexibleSpace: Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: <Color>[Colors.blue, Colors.pink],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      title: TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: 'Search',
          hintStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
            borderSide: const BorderSide(
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
          prefixIcon: const Icon(
            Icons.search,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => const Size.fromHeight(80);
}
```

And in the `HomeScreen` like this:

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
      appBar: SearchBarWidget(),
    );
  }
}
```

If this is not what you are thinking, please provide an example.

Comment: or use `kToolbarHeight` instead of `50` to make it same with `AppBar`

Comment: Still, I can't see the box.

Comment: @basakcglyn I have just seen the issue, you are creating a new `Scaffold` inside the `AppBar`, I am updating my answer with an example and with an example screenshot, let me know if is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Fixing the PreferredSizeWidget Mixin Issue:
Instead of using with (mixin) for PreferredSizeWidget, you should use implements since PreferredSizeWidget is an interface and not a mixin. Your initial attempt was on the right track

### search_bar_widget.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SearchBarWidget extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  SearchBarWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  final Size preferredSize = Size.fromHeight(80.0); // Define your height here

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: preferredSize.height, // Make sure to give the container a height
      color: Colors.pink,
    );
  }
}
```

Notes:

1. Changed the class definition to use "implements PreferredSizeWidget".
2. Set a defined height for the "preferredSize" property.
3. Specified the height of the Container widget using "preferredSize.height".

### home_screen.dart:

No changes needed.

Comment: Still, I can't see the box.